# Change the value of a variable on the fly depending on the selection of a Select

Tags: javascript, php, select, drop-down-menu

I have the following PHP code where I print my HTML and I have a variable $price and another $numofguests

```
<?php
echo '$' . $price ;

$i = 1;
//This print values of number of guest for example: 1,2,3,4
echo 'Select Number of Guests';
echo '<select name="numberofguests">';
while ($i <= $numofguests):
        echo $i;
    echo '<option value="' .$i. '">' .$i. '</option>'; 
        $i++;
endwhile;
echo '</select>'; 
?>
```

How could I print out on the fly a total price depending on the user selection?

Example: let's say that $price = $5 and that number of guest options are: 1,2,3

So by default num of guest is going to be 1 and total price = $5

But if user select num of guest = 2 I would like the total price to change to $10 and if num of guest = 3 I would like the total price to change to $15

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
 <div id="pricediv"></div>
    <?php
    $numofguests = 5;
    $i = 1;
    echo 'Select Number of Guests'."</br>";
    echo '<select name="numberofguests" onchange="total(this.value)">';
    while ($i <= $numofguests):
            echo $i;
        echo '<option value="' .$i. '">' .$i. '</option>'; 
            $i++;
    endwhile;
    echo '</select>'; 
    ?>

    <script>
    function total(guest){
    var price = guest*5;
    document.getElementById("pricediv").innerHTML="Price for "+guest+" guests is $"+price; 
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your php code as is:

```
# index.php
<?php
$i = 1;
?>
<select id="room-selector" name="numberofguests">
  <?php while ($i <= $numofguests): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php $i++; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<p>No. of guest selected : <span id="guest-count"></span></p>
```

Now in the javascript:

```
$("#room-selector").change(function() {
  var price = 5; // or var price = <?php echo $price; ?>;
  $('#guest-count').text($(this).val() * price);
});
```

to take the value form the select drop-down when it is changes and put the value in the span.

Demo: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/reduwanora/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

So, you will want to use Javascript to update the price label in the client.  You can create a simple function that calculates the price and displays it.

You can have the function execute  whenever the select list changes by adding the `onchange` attribute to your `<select>`

Something like this:

```
<?PHP
   $price = 10;
   $numofguests = 5;

   $options="";

   while ($i <= $numofguests):
       $options .= '<option value="' .$i. '">' .$i. '</option>'; 
       $i++;
   endwhile;
?>

<html>
    <p id="price"><?= $price; ?></p>

    <select name="numberofguests" id="numberofguests" onchange="updatePrice()">
        <?= $options; ?>
    </select>

    <script>
        function updatePrice(){
            // set the value of the JS price with the value from PHP
            var price = <?= $price; ?>;
            var qty = document.getElementById("numberofguests").value;
            var totalPrice = price * qty;

            var destination = document.getElementById("price");

            destination.innerHTML = totalPrice;
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an onChange event of the select to run a javascript function that changes the HTML where you print the total price.  To be more specific, I would need to see the HTML code where you print the total price.